# What are the purposes of `sudo -v &&` and `sh /dev/stdin` here?

Tags: shell, software-installation, sudo, stdin

From https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
```

What is the purpose of `sudo -v &&` here, given that `man sudo` says

> ```
>  -v, --validate
> ```
>
> Update the user's cached credentials, authenticating the user if necessary.  For the sudoers plugin, this extends the sudo
>   timeout for another 15 minutes by
>                    default, but does not run a command.  Not all security policies support cached credentials.

What is the purpose of `sh /dev/stdin`? (In Ubuntu 18.04, `sh` is dash)

Thanks.

Comment: Reading the code before executing it is good advice. I would rather `wget -nv -O- script.sh | cat` first to read the contents of the file!

Answer (score 6):

> What is the purpose of `sudo -v &&` here?

I believe this minimizes user surprise. Consider two scenarios:

1. sudo is *not* configured to require a password for commands (the NOPASSWD tag)

versus:

2. sudo *is* configured to require a password for commands

In the first scenario, both calls to sudo succeed without any prompts. Problem solved!

In the second scenario, there are again two possibilities: either the user has recently authenticated to sudo or they have not.

- If they have recently authenticated, `sudo -v` simply updates the timestamp of their cached credentials.
- If the user has *not* authenticated to sudo recently, it will prompt them for their password; once authenticated, their credentials are then cached.

Once the `sudo -v` process succeeds, the second `sudo sh /dev/stdin` call should use their cached credential and run uninterrupted.

Consider the alternative (where sudo is still configured to prompt for a password) where there is no initial `sudo -v` command. In this case, `wget` may have written output to stdout or stderr, which may cause the user to miss seeing it and wonder why nothing is happening.

> What is the purpose of `sh /dev/stdin`?

Here `sh` is being called with a parameter as the `command_file` that is a special file -- a link to stdin.

> NAME
> dash — command interpreter (shell)
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  dash ...
>       [command_file [argument ...]]
> ```

As a result, sh reads the command_file, expecting and executing commands from it. That special stdin "file" is connected via the pipe to the output from `wget`, so the end result is that the contents of the URL are sent to a root-level shell.

I do not know why the Calibre project specifically chose that syntax. Alternatives include:

- `... | sudo sh`
- `... | sudo sh -`